# How can I disable manually the remove button from the rich:pickList?

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm working with the rich:pickList and it's working fine. I just need to find a way to disable the remove button at the moment I select an item located in the target list.
I suppose it could be done with JavaScript or JQuery but I have no experience with that.

The most I've done is to get the text of the selected item of the target list, but I would like to obtain the entire object represented by that item. Besides, I have looked for the button in the DOM tree but the button has no id, so I can't figure out how to find the button in order to can give it the right style class to disable it, and how to do this!

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the attribute of `rich:pickList`  `removeVisible`. This will display/undisplayed the remove button in the component.

Hope this helps. 
-cheers

Comment: I'm using RichFaces 4.2 and the pickList doesn't have that attribute you say. Maybe what you say works in RichFaces 3.3. Thanks for your response.